# Pithy pedagogical examples of integrals from $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{C}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I'm looking for pithy examples of integrals of the form
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}} f(\mathbf{x}) \, \mathrm{d}x 
\end{align*}
where $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$, to demonstrate high-dimensional numerical quadrature.

Of course quantum mechanics is the intended use, but I'd rather have something more explicit. In 1D, a great example is the complex Bessel function
\begin{align*}
J_{n}(z) := \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(n\tau - z\sin(\tau)\, \mathrm{d}\tau
\end{align*}

Comment: The first one I think of is that if     $J=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx $    then     $J=\sqrt {\pi} \;$    because     $J^2=\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy=\int_{r=0}^{\infty}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}re^{-r^2}d\theta dr=\pi. $       (Change to polar co-ordinates.)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: That is not complex valued.